# MimeKit.ParseException: Unexpected token at offset 18

Tags: asp.net-core, email-client, mimekit

I have **SPA application and asp.net core 3.1 web api** and **MimeKit** for email service.

**When user register the server sends confirmation email and everything is okay.
But on 1 phone device the server throws exception when the email contains underscore.**

The **problematic email is "pristi_1900@abv.bg"** and the **error** that server throws is:

```
MimeKit.ParseException: Unexpected token at offset 18
   at MimeKit.MailboxAddress.set_Address(String value)
   at MimeKit.MailboxAddress..ctor(Encoding encoding, String name, String address)
   at MimeKit.MailboxAddress..ctor(String address)
```

The weird part is that I connected the phone browser to my pc via chrome dev tools for remote debugging and when I did via pc browser emulator its working.

Note that:

- the email is 18 chars longs so it basically fails on the and
- The email is sent with https post in body and it is logged properly
  on the server
- Email that contains dot(".") is working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I upgraded MimeKit from 2.6 to 3.2 and its working properly now.**

Answer (score 0):

If there are white spaces in the email address this error can happen